# Why "If I had X...." is translated to "si tuviera X"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario, subjuntivo

**Tuviera** is the subjunctive form of **tengo**. Subjunctive form is about wish, desire, doubts, not being certain, etc.

How can the subjunctive form be used in the sentence to mean

> "If I had X"?

Why not **tendría** instead:

> "si tendría X"?

Comment: "Si yo tuviera una escoba, ¡cuántas cosas barrería!" How come isn't that a wish or desire?

Comment: @nylypej It is the equivalent of the subjunctive in English: If I were taller, I could dunk a basketball; If Peter were a rich man, he could drive a fancy car; John spends money as if he were a millionaire. Many native English speakers would typically use ‘was’ instead of ‘were’ to express such hypothetical ideas, albeit this is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Traveller, you're wrong. Instead of "could" ---> "would"

Comment: @nlypej Maybe, but my point was focused on the correct use of ‘were’ as the subjunctive mood in English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Because "tendría" means "I would have".

You don't say `If I would have sommething, I ...`, do you? No, you say `If I had something`

2) This is the perfect place for a subjunctive. If you are saying

> If I had something, I would...

That's because you don't have it yet. Otherwise you'd be saying

> Since I have it, I will...

But you do not have it, that's why you're using "had" and not "have". That's a conditional. Second conditional to be precise. `If I had something, I would...`

So, the part "If I had something" is not a fact. You don't have that thing, you *wish** you had it, you're imaginin what you would do if you had it. Anyway you see it, it is not a real situation, but a desired/imagined one. Consequently, it takes the subjunctive.